# Why non-virtual function call is successful even after dynamic_cast is failed?

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Below is code snippet,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    void print() const
    {
        cout << "In A::print()\n";
    }

    virtual void show()
    {
        cout << "In A::show()\n";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void print() const
    {
        cout << "In B::print()\n";
    }

    void show()
    {
        cout << "In B::show()\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    A* a = new A;
    a->show();
    a->print();

    B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
    cout << b << endl;
    b->print();
    b->show();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is output when I run this (I am using Visual c++ compiler),

```
In A::show()
In A::print()
00000000
In B::print()

and then program stops working ....
```

There are two questions,
 1. Why/How call to function `B::print()` is successful even after `dynamic_cast` is failed since value of `b` is 0 as seen in output?

2. Why program stopped working when `B::show()` is called (given that
   call to `B::print()` was successful in line before it)?

Comment: you should understand the difference btw it does not guarantee to work and it guarantees not to work. Nobody requires compiler to generate code to fail explicitly.

Comment: Not quite duplicate. Here, 'this' pointer is used implicitly, by VMT, in the second case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No surprise.

1. b is NULL as dynamic cast is failed
2. b->print() is ok. Well, `this` is NULL but it never used in its body.
3. b->show() fails. Despite it also doesn't use `this` explicitly, it still needs a Virtual Methods table lookup to determine the proper subclass method address. A pointer to the virtual table is a (hidden) field of B class; as b is NULL, program crashes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got the point :)